# Does Multiple Triggers for the Same Event & Action Time Impact OLD and NEW?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, sql-update, mysql-5.7

Let's say I have two BEFORE UPDATE triggers on the same table. We'll call them trigger A and trigger B. Order is enforced, so A will always be executed first, and B will always be executed second.

Will OLD and NEW reference the same values in the body of both A and B?

Or will the NEW values of A become the OLD values of B? Meaning B is referencing a new UPDATE statement, which is a product of A?

Answer (score 0):

The OLD values reference the row before the UPDATE. That is, before any of the triggers execute. These never change during the triggers.

The NEW values reference the row with values you mean to change.

One trigger may modifies the NEW values. Then the subsequent trigger will see the modified values, still in the NEW row.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, x int);

mysql> insert into mytable set x = 1;
    
mysql> delimiter $$

mysql> create trigger t1 before update on mytable 
 for each row begin set NEW.x = NEW.x + 1; end$$

mysql> create trigger t2 before update on mytable 
  for each row follows t1 begin set @x_old = OLD.x; set @x_new = NEW.x; end$$

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> update mytable set x = 10;

mysql> select @x_old, @x_new;
+--------+--------+
| @x_old | @x_new |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |     11 |
+--------+--------+
```